# Terraform -- Failed to save state

Tags: terraform

need your help. I try to create policy which won't allow to upload objects which aren't encrypted either KMS or SSE. Also, I use s3 state bucket and dynamodb lock. Backend with s3 has encryption key KMS. During my creation I apply policy to the bucket which stores my terraform state file, it applies and then throw the following error:

```
│ Error: Failed to save state
│ 
│ Error saving state: failed to upload state: AccessDenied: Access Denied
│       status code: 403, request id: ************************, host id: **********************************
╵
╷
│ Error: Failed to persist state to backend
│ 
│ The error shown above has prevented Terraform from writing the updated state to the configured backend. To allow for recovery, the state has been written to the file "errored.tfstate" in the current working
│ directory.
│ 
│ Running "terraform apply" again at this point will create a forked state, making it harder to recover.
│ 
│ To retry writing this state, use the following command:
│     terraform state push errored.tfstate
│
```

**My backend**

```
backend "s3" {
    profile = "default"
    bucket = "bucket_name"
    key    = "my_state.tfstate"
    region = "region"
    kms_key_id = "arn_to_key"
    dynamodb_table = "state_table"
}
```

**Policy**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Sid_1",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn_to_account_role",
                    "arn_to_account_role"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/*",
            "Condition": {
                "Null": {
                    "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "true"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Sid_2",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn_to_account_role",
                    "arn_to_account_role"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": [
                        "aws:kms",
                        "AES256"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Current version terraform which I use is **Terraform v0.15.4**

Provider of AWS is **~> 3.20.0**

Comment: You are trying to apply the policy to the state file bucket. I don't think that will work if you already have a state file stored in that path.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `encrypt = true` to your backend config

```
backend "s3" {
    profile = "default"
    bucket = "bucket_name"
    key    = "my_state.tfstate"
    region = "region"
    kms_key_id = "arn_to_key"
    dynamodb_table = "state_table"
    encrypt        = true
}
```